# JSTL Form:select in table cell inside c:forEach

Tags: jsp, jstl

I want to have a dropdown list inside a table cell for every record/row in a list

customerList holds Connection entity (with customerGroup and assignedVendor properties)

vendorList holds Vendor entity (with name and customerID property

Here is what I have so far:

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/vendorAdmin/viewClients/${vendorGroupID}" method="post" >

                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover " id="sample_1">
                                <thead>
                                <tr class="bg-success">

                                    <th>Admin Name</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Username</th>
                                    <th>Phone</th>
                                    <th>Assign To</th>
                                    <th></th>

                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <c:forEach items="${customerList}" var="connection" varStatus="cStatus">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>${customerList[cStatus.index].customerGroup.name}</td>

                                        <td class="text-center">${customerList[cStatus.index].customerGroup.customerList[0].email}</td>
                                        <td class="text-center">${customerList[cStatus.index].customerGroup.customerList[0].username}</td>
                                        <td class="text-center">${customerList[cStatus.index].customerGroup.customerList[0].phone}</td>
                                        <td>

                                            <form:select path="customerList[${cStatus.index}].assignedVendor.customerID">
                                                <form:options items="${vendorList}" itemLabel="name" itemValue="customerID"/>
                                            </form:select>

                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="<spring:url value="/vendorAdmin/sendMessageToCustomer/${vendorGroupID}/${customerList[cStatus.index].customerGroup.userGroupID}" />"
                                            ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-message "></span></a>

                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </table>
                        </form:form>
```

Error:

```
 ERROR o.s.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectTag - Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:144)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:154)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:422)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.SelectTag.writeTagContent(SelectTag.java:194)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:84)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
```

Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

EDIT: I apologise for not being clear enough.  The problem is NOT that I can not get the customerList from the controller.  Everything works fine EXCEPT the `form:select` It feels like I am making a mistake in the `path` and cannot access the field. Hope this make it a bit clearer

Comment: It's impossible without code.

Answer (score 0):

Spring tablib  expect a command name or model attribute on which it can bind value of input.

Let's say you have a class like this -

```
User{
    private String name;
    //Add getters setters
}
```

from controller where page is loading

```
@RequestMapping("/form")
public String getFormPage(Model model){
   model.addAttribute("user",new User());
}
```

then in form.jsp

```
<form:form modelAttribute="user">/*user is set in model attribute in controller*/
    <form:input path="name" placeholder="Input name">
</form:form>
```